# What is the pythonic way to sort a list with multiple attributes, such that the first is sorted reversely but the second is not?

Tags: python, sorting

Given a list

```
[ ['a','b'], ['x','y'], ['a','y'], ['x', 'b'] ]
```

How can I sort it in a way that the first element is sorted decreasingly, but the second element is sorted increasingly when the first element equal? The strings can be arbitrarily long in this list.

The sorted list should be

```
[ ['x', 'b'], ['x', 'y'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'y'] ]
```

I'm thinking about using one single call of `sorted`, but making up a key to reflect this seems not working.

Comment: The Javastic way to do this would be to create a custom `Comparator` that implements the customized collation rules that you want ... and then pass the custom rules to the Arrays.sort() method.  In Java 8 this can be done with a lambda, anonymous class instance, or concrete class instance.  Python would have something similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can sort it twice (Python uses a stable sort that performs well on already-sorted portions):

```
>>> l = [ ['a','b'], ['x','y'], ['a','y'], ['x', 'b'] ]
>>> sorted(sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[1]), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
[['x', 'b'], ['x', 'y'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'y']]
```

Or you can use `ord()` to get an integer and negate it:

```
>>> l = [ ['a','b'], ['x','y'], ['a','y'], ['x', 'b'] ]
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: (-ord(x[0]), x[1]))
[['x', 'b'], ['x', 'y'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'y']]
```

Comment: Seems like calling `sorted` twice is inevitable in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

The way I thought at first time was:

```
l.sort(key=lambda e: (255 - ord(e[0]), e[1]))
```

But this way the element must be a tuple (I understood that’s the case), and de first element of each tuple must be a string/character.

Better solutions can evolve from here.

Comment: What is the `255` for?

Comment: Really for nothing. I have just made a quick&dirty draft – the idea was keeping de range between 0 and 255, the character range, but it’s not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2 you can do this:

```
>>> l = [ ['a','b'], ['x','y'], ['a','y'], ['x', 'b'] ]
>>>
>>> sorted(l, lambda (a, b), (c, d): cmp(c, a) or cmp(b, d))
[['x', 'b'], ['x', 'y'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'y']]
```

The same thing in Python 3 is possible, but ugly:

```
>>> import functools
>>> sorted(l, key=functools.cmp_to_key(lambda a, b: (a[0] < b[0]) - (a[0] > b[0]) or (a[1] > b[1]) - (a[1] < b[1])))
[['x', 'b'], ['x', 'y'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'y']]
```

Or with a helper:

```
>>> def cmp(a, b):
    return (a > b) - (a < b)

>>> sorted(l, key=functools.cmp_to_key(lambda a, b: cmp(b[0], a[0]) or cmp(a[1], b[1])))
[['x', 'b'], ['x', 'y'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'y']]
```